# Gridstack Auto Resize When Fullscreen Browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, gridstack

Hello i have a plugin gridstack, And already use this plugin
But i'm have a problem.

When i'm full screen mode browser my page show whitespace, but if not fullscreen mode this whitespace has gone

**Fullscreen Mode**
[image]

**Not Fullscreen Mode**
[image]

I'm confuse to fix this
this is my code

**index.php**
in pastebin [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/CGjrhfPc)

```
<?php include "element/connection.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>DMS | PJB UP. Muara Karang</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo-pjb.png">

  <!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
  <link href="dist/js/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="dist/js/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="dist/js/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
  <script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

   <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
   <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- iCheck -->
   <script src="plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Highchart -->
   <script  type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/highchart/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script  type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/highchart/highcharts-more.js"></script>
   <script  type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/highchart/exporting.js"></script>

   <!-- GridStack -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/js/gridstack/dist/gridstack.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/js/gridstack/dist/gridstack-extra.css"/>
   <script src="dist/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script src="dist/js/lodash.min.js"></script>
   <script src="dist/js/gridstack/dist/gridstack.js"></script>
   <script src="dist/js/gridstack/dist/gridstack.jQueryUI.js"></script>

   <!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
   <link href="dist/js/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="dist/js/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="dist/js/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
        .grid-stack {
        }

        .grid-stack-item-content {
            color: #2c3e50;
            text-align: center;
        }
   </style>
</head>
 <body>
            <div id="carousel-example-generic-v1" class="carousel slide widget-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <?php 
                $count_circle=0;
                $data_circle = mysqli_query($con,"select * from dasboard where active_data='Yes' order by sorting_data asc");
                    while($circle=mysqli_fetch_object($data_circle))
                    { ?>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic-v1" data-slide-to="<?php echo $count_circle; ?>" 
                    class="circle <?php if($count_circle==0){ echo "active"; }?>">
                    </li>
                <?php 
                    $count_circle++;
                    } ?>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <?php 
                    $count_data=0;
                    $data_dash = mysqli_query($con,"select * from dasboard where active_data='Yes' order by sorting_data asc");
                    while($dash=mysqli_fetch_object($data_dash))
                    { ?>
                        <div class="item <?php if($count_data==0){ echo "active"; }?>">
                                <div id="grid_<?php echo $count_data ?>" class="widget-gradient widget-gradient-body grid-stack">
                                </div>

                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        LoadPage();
                                        function LoadPage()
                                        {
                                            var options = {
                                            float: false
                                            };

                                            $('#grid_<?php echo $count_data ?>').gridstack(options);
                                            new function () {
                                                this.serializedData = <?php echo $dash->data_show.";" ?>

                                                this.grid = $('#grid_<?php echo $count_data ?>').data('gridstack'); 

                                                this.loadGrid = function () {
                                                    this.grid.removeAll();
                                                    var items = GridStackUI.Utils.sort(this.serializedData);
                                                    _.each(items, function (node, i) {
                                                        this.grid.addWidget($('<div id="induk"><div  class="grid-stack-item-content">' +  node.content + '</div></div>'),
                                                            node.x, node.y, node.w, node.h);
                                                        this.grid.movable('.grid-stack-item', false);
                                                        this.grid.resizable('.grid-stack-item', false); 
                                                    }, this);
                                                    return false;
                                                }.bind(this);

                                                this.loadGrid(); 
                                            };

                                            var str = '<?php echo $dash->data_gen ?>';
                                            var str_array = str.split(',');
                                            for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
                                                call_data(i);     
                                            }


                                            function call_data(i){
                                                    str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
                                                          var widget =  $("#data_"+str_array[i]).val();
                                                          var convert_data = str_array[i];

                                                          $("#del_"+convert_data).remove();     //remove delete icon
                                                          $("#label_"+convert_data).remove();   //remove label


                                                           var height_div_parent   =  $('#wg_'+convert_data).closest('.grid-stack-item-content').height();
                                                           var width_div_parent    = $('#wg_'+convert_data).closest('.grid-stack-item-content').width();

                                                           var formData   = 'id_tr=<?php echo $dash->id_tr_halaman_dasboard ?>&id_tr_dt='+str_array[i]+'&id_tr_widget='+widget+'&width='+width_div_parent+'&height='+height_div_parent;


                                                             $.ajax({
                                                                 type: "POST",
                                                                 dataType: "html",
                                                                 url: "element/get_data_dashboard.php",
                                                                 data: formData,
                                                                 success: function(msg){
                                                                    if(msg == ''){
                                                                        $("#wg_"+convert_data).empty(); 
                                                                        $("#wg_"+convert_data).html("");                                                        
                                                                    }
                                                                    else{
                                                                        $("#wg_"+convert_data).empty(); 
                                                                        $("#wg_"+convert_data).html(msg);
                                                                    }

                                                                 }
                                                              }); 
                                                }
                                        }
                                    </script>
                        </div>
                    <?php 
                    $count_data++;
                    } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**element/get_data_dashboard.php**
in Pastebin [click here](http://pastebin.com/t90J7gnz)

```
<?php 
    include "connection.php";
    $id_tr        = $_REQUEST['id_tr'];         //header dashboard
    $id_tr_widget = $_REQUEST['id_tr_widget'];  //id tr widget
    $id_tr_dt     = $_REQUEST['id_tr_dt'];      //id tr detail
    $width        = $_REQUEST['width'];         //width
    $height       = $_REQUEST['height'];        //height
    $mw_wg    = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con,"select * from tr_widget where id_tr_widget='".$id_tr_widget."'"));
    $my_konek = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con,"select * from connection where id_con='".$mw_wg->id_con."'"));
    $sql_view = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT query  from sql_view where  id_sql_view='".$mw_wg->id_sql_view."'"));

    $id_type_widget = $mw_wg->id_type_widget;
        if($my_konek->port=="" or $my_konek->port==null)
        {
            $mydb = new mysqli($my_konek->host,$my_konek->username,$my_konek->pwd,$my_konek->database_name);
                if($mydb->connect_errno > 0){
                        die('Unable to connect to database' . $mydb->connect_error);
                }
        }
        else
        {
            $mydb = new mysqli($my_konek->host,$my_konek->username,$my_konek->pwd,$my_konek->database_name,$my_konek->port);
                if($mydb->connect_errno > 0){
                        die('Unable to connect to database' . $mydb->connect_error);
                }
        }
        // Image Slider
         if($id_type_widget=="9"){ 
         $RandomAccountNumber = uniqid();
         ?>

                            <center><div id="owl-demo_<?php echo $id_tr?>_<?php echo $id_tr_dt?>_<?php echo $RandomAccountNumber ?>" class="owl-carousel">
                                <?php 
                                   $list_value  = $mw_wg->file_name;
                                   $var=explode('***zzz****',$list_value);
                                   $count = count($var);
                                   foreach($var as $row) {
                                    if (--$count <= 0) {
                                        break;
                                    }   
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="item"><img onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='images/no_image.png';" style="height:<?php echo $height?>px; width:<?php echo $width?>px" src="images/images_video/<?php echo $row?>"></div>
                                <?php } ?>  
                            </div></center>

                            <script>
                             $(document).ready(function() {
                                  $("#owl-demo_<?php echo $id_tr?>_<?php echo $id_tr_dt?>_<?php echo $RandomAccountNumber ?>").owlCarousel({
                                  autoPlay   : true,    
                                  navigation : false,
                                  singleItem : true,
                                  pagination: false
                                  });
                                });
                            </script>

        <?php }
        // Video
        else if($id_type_widget=="7"){ 
        $ext_file     = end((explode(".",$mw_wg->file_name)))
         ?>

                        <head>
                          <link href="dist/js/videojs/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

                          <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
                          <script src="dist/js/videojs/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
                        </head>

                        <body>
                          <video  controls loop autoplay preload="auto" id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" style="height:<?php echo $height?>px; width:<?php echo $width?>px" data-setup="{}" poster="images/fff.png">
                            <source src="images/images_video/<?php echo $mw_wg->file_name; ?>" type='video/<?php echo $ext_file?>'>
                          </video>

                          <script src="dist/js/videojs/video.js"></script>
                        </body>

        <?php } ?>
```

See this link [click here](http://www.lefgrin.com/grid_stack/)

I'm confused to remove whitespace when fullscreen mode.
Help Me Thank's

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle of the HTML output **after** the PHP executes, or update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://www.lefgrin.com/grid_stack/

Comment: The whitespace below your videos appears both fullscreen and non-fullscreen. I'm guessing you have a monitor with a height that perfectly matches the edge of your video when not fullscreen.

Comment: so, what a solution :(
i confused, can you fix this ?

Comment: i'm already change to all image slider but still show whitespace 
http://www.lefgrin.com/grid_stack/